# What are the effects of setting COMPRESSVALUE in initramfs to values other than the defaults

Tags: linux, initramfs

When configuring `initramfs` (at least on Ubuntu and Debian) one can choose between various compression methods, and, also, a `COMPRESSVALUE` that varies in meaning (0-9 for some, 1-9 for others, and 0 to 19 for `zstd`). At least in Ubuntu, a commented out line says the default is 1. What happens when you set a higher value? Would it try to compress more, or is the default value of 1 the optimal in terms of compression?

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, it seems the general rule is that the higher the number, the higher the compression and the longer it takes to compress with diminishing returns. For `COMPRESS=xz`, it took the test machine slightly more than 3 minutes to generate a 52MB image. With the value 1, it took about 30 seconds to generate an image with 62MB. With a value of 5, it took about 1 minute and the initrd image was 54MB in size.

Performance on boot may not reflect these times (which are for compression) since the booting process works in the opposite direction. This is because the bootloader can freely utilize SIMD extensions, acceleration tricks, and any supported hardware on your platform, which may incur higher penalties if used within a running Linux kernel.